# Latency in Serial communication using FTDI and ReadFile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, serial-port, microcontroller, ftdi

I've noticed a strange delay while communicating with an FTDI device through Virtual Comm Port in C/C++ (Visual Studio).

I send a command (11 characters) to the device which returns a string (18 characters) and takes around 5ms to complete (send + receive). The communication is done at 57600 baud.

After some testing I discovered that executing this code in my computer gives a good time (5ms), while doing it in other computers takes around 15 to 20 ms. The curious thing here is that this effect does not appear when using System.IO.Ports through C# to communicate with the FTDI (I always get execution times of 5ms, no matter what PC is executing this).
Time in this particular application is critical, so removing those additional ms is very important.

The latency of the port buffer has been manually set to 1ms (device manager).

I presume this should be related to the way I open the port, but I've tested many solutions and nothing works.

Here is the code I use to open the port:

```
hCom = CreateFile(DevPath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if ( hCom==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    CloseHandle(hCom);
    hCom = NULL;
    return false;
} else {
    if (!SetupComm(hCom,2048,2048)) {
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        hCom = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    try {

        dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
        GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

        //No Flow control
        dcb.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
        dcb.ByteSize = 8;         // Setting ByteSize = 8
        dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;// Setting StopBits = 1
        dcb.Parity   = NOPARITY;  // Setting Parity = None
        dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
        dcb.fParity = FALSE;
        dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
        dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
        dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
        dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
        dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
        dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = FALSE;
        dcb.fOutX = FALSE;
        dcb.fInX = FALSE;

        if(!SetCommState(hCom, &dcb)) {
            CloseHandle(hCom);
            hCom  = NULL;
            return false;
        }
    } catch (std::string strCatchErr) {
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        hCom = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    CommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 40;
    CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hCom, &CommTimeouts)) {
        CloseHandle(hCom);
        hCom = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    //purge port buffers
    PurgeComm(hCom, PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT);

    return true;
```

The process of reading and writing to the port is done using plain ReadFile and WriteFile instructions:

```
DWORD BytesRead = 0;
DWORD TotalBytesRead = 0;
DWORD BytesToRead = 20;
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
BOOL bSuccess;
char rxbuffer[1024];
char * InBuffer;
int fRun = 1;

//Send data
PurgeComm(hCom, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_RXABORT);
WriteFile(hCom, "TESTCMD001\n", (DWORD)11, &bytesWritten, NULL);

//receive data
InBuffer = &rxbuffer[0];

while(fRun) {
    BytesRead = 0;
    bSuccess = ReadFile(hCom, InBuffer, BytesToRead, &BytesRead, NULL);
    if ( bSuccess==TRUE ) {
        if (BytesRead>0) {
            TotalBytesRead += BytesRead;
            rxbuffer[TotalBytesRead] = '\0';
            InBuffer = &rxbuffer[TotalBytesRead];
            if ( strchr(rxbuffer, '\n')!=NULL ) fRun = 0;
        } //IF_BytesRead>0
    } //IF_ReadFile
}
```

NOTE! -> this is a simplified version of the code, so there could be mistakes.

Does anyone experienced something like this before?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: some percentage of this is operating system (did you specify one? one would assume windows) and driver.  While uart is quite slow, should still expect some overhead.

Comment: Hi @old_timer, I forgot to mention it, but has been tested in Win 7, 8.1 and 10, with better and worse hardware (same result in all of them). The development PC uses Win7, but testing it in other win7 PCs has the same bad effect.
FTDI driver is up to date in all the PCs.

Comment: you used win7 on the same hardware or are you changing more than one thing at a time?  win7 on some other machine could be the machine not win7 for example.  32 bit vs 64 bit.

Comment: @old_timer the development PC has win7 installed. I tested it in other win7 (32 and 64 bit), and also in win8.1 (64 bit) and win10 (64 bit) all in different hardware (better actually), of course. A friend suggested yesterday that this could be caused by a windows update, since the development PC is and off-line isolated PC and has not been updated for years.

Comment: I think this is all about USB hardware - some machines have arcane and less-than-ideal setups of USB hubs and whatnot between the CPU and the real USB line where your FTDI sits. Maybe a try with a high quality USB hub on a different port. After all, the master-slave protocol must emulate an asynchronous communication channel and there are plenty of timing pitfalls.

Comment: Hi @Vroomfondel, unfortunatelly this is a little bit more complex and not related to the USB hardware itself. Since in the very same machine, accessing using .NET native ports programming or python works fine, while accessing to the ports using C++/WINAPI does not. With the very same config parameters for the port.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless, do a test with where you change the used USB port. It could very well be that the WINAPI is trying to (unnecessarily) buffer the stream on some ports because the hardware told it so.

Comment: Thank you @Vroomfondel, I already tried that with no difference in the results. I even bought a good PCIe USB card, just in case internal USB hubs were playing an important role, but as I said, that made no difference.

Comment: @Carles if you change two things or more at a time (win7 on machine a and win10 on machine b) then you cannot make an argument that it is the windows version, nor the machine.  Thats all i am trying to say.   Now that you have a pcie card moving that from machine to machine and slot to slot also helps isolate the issue.  It sounds very much like software, thus my prior comments.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the software and demonstrate it is hardware then boot DOS.  (I am not joking in any way) cannot converge if you dont eliminate the unknowns (rather than creating even more)

Comment: Hi @old_timer thanks for your suggestions. Right now I'm creating a console application based in a static compile of my code and we'll see what happen.

Comment: @old_timer, I performed a static compile of the whole code, instead of using a DLL, in a target console/DOS program and it does have the very same effect, so this should be an issue related to either WINAPI32 functions or visual studio compiler/linker. Since this does not happen in .NET, Python nor FreePascal.

Comment: OMG! After one week (literally) struggling with the issue, I've just fixed it. You won't image what was causing the latency: inside the function that reads back all the data from the port (the function that contains ReadFile()) there was a tiny delay (50us) that was done before starting the reception: std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(50))
Well, for some reason, this delay behaves differently depending on the computer, taking up to 1ms to be executed. This, repeated over time causes "general" delays in the program up to 200ms.
Thanks for your time @old_timer